# Java PreparedStatement Comment on Table

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement

I'm familiar with using java prepared statements to insert/update on a table. In oracle you can add a comment on a table, how would I use a preparedstatement to do that?

This was my initial attempt with no luck;

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("comment on table my_table is q'[?]'");
stmt.setString(1, description);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: `comment` is a DDL statement so you can't use bind variables just like you can't use bind variables in a `create table` statement.  You'd need to assemble the full SQL statement and send that to Oracle.  Plus, DDL statements are actually executed in the prepare phase so it wouldn't make sense to use a `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use system Oracle table and set comment there with `PreparedStatement`, like this:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(
    "UPDATE user_tab_comments SET comments = ? WHERE table_name = 'my_table'");
```

Or try to use simple statement:

```
String commentOnTableSQL = String.format("COMMENT ON TABLE my_table is '%s'", comment);
Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
statement.execute(commentOnTableSQL);
```

Comment: I hope to heck that an `update` on `user_tab_comments` would fail.  Directly updating a data dictionary table is a terrible idea.  It's unsupported and if it works, that almost always introduces some sort of subtle corruption.  Oracle generally prevents you from doing that but if you have enough privileges and you get "lucky" you might find a view that you are technically able to modify.